# auth0 authorization api call returns 200 status yet still getting error response

Tags: angular, authentication, error-handling, auth0, angular-httpclient

angular http call:

```
login(){
    const loginstring = 'https://<removed>.auth0.com/authorize?' +
      'response_type=token&' +
      'client_id=<removed>&' +
      'connection=null&' +
      'redirect_uri=<removed>';
    this.http.get(loginstring, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(
      (req:any)=>{
        console.log('this is the http response');
        console.log(req);
      });

  }
```

response

Not using code formating as it is eaiser to read without it.

ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4200/", ok: false, …}headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}status: 200statusText: "OK"url: "http://localhost:4200/"ok: falsename: "HttpErrorResponse"message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/"error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()
    at XMLHtt…, text: "↵↵↵  ↵↵"}**proto**: HttpResponseBase

httpclient defaults to returning the json of the response, and that is something I am actively researching. But I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You get `200` because you succeed to get to the server but you have issues with the payload.
It seemed you need to send JSON and you sending something that started with `<` which isn't JSON.
you can use this site to check if you send valid JSON: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So pretty easy fix just had to change the response type to text.

```
const loginstring = 'https://portaltech.auth0.com/authorize?' +
      'response_type=code&' +
      'client_id=MOqNyn7qyRhJdCOv5QHCUGkmjAv6Wied&' +
      'connection=null&' +
      'redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/';
    this.http.get(loginstring, {responseType: 'text', observe:'response'}).subscribe(
      (req:any)=>{
        console.log('this is the http response');
        console.log(req.body);
        this.innerhtml = req.body;
```